# Cannot set unknown member Interaction.Behaviors

Tags: wpf

I am getting this error when I tried to add behavior to a Framework Element inside a template

Min example:

```
xmlns:interact="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
.....
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and when I tried to run the application I am getting

> "Cannot set unknown member
>   '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity}Interaction.Behaviors'."

Note that this only happens if I define this style inside a resource dictionary. If I cut and paste this style into `Window.Resources` everything works nicely. How can I fix this?